# how to equal two doublepointers

Tags: c, global, local, dynamic-arrays

Ok, hello all!

I got this to work:

```
char **list = NULL;   // global
int number_of_strings = 0;   // global

void empty_list_of_strings(void);
void add_string_to_list(char *string);
void print_list_of_strings(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    add_string_to_list("Warrior");
    add_string_to_list("Magician");
    add_string_to_list("Pirate");

    print_list_of_strings();

    empty_list_of_strings();

    return 0;
}

void empty_list_of_strings(void) {
    int k=0;

    if(list != NULL) {
        for(k=0; k number_of_strings; k++) { // less than
            if(list[k] != NULL) {
                free(list[k]);
            list[k] = NULL;
        }
    }

    free(list);
    list = NULL;
    number_of_strings = 0;
    }
}

void add_string_to_list(char *string) {
    if(list != NULL) {
        list=realloc(list, (number_of_strings + 2) * sizeof(char*));
        list[number_of_strings]=malloc( (strlen(string) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(list[number_of_strings], string);
        number_of_strings++;
        list[number_of_strings]=NULL;
    } else {
        list = malloc( (number_of_strings +2) *sizeof(char *));
        list[number_of_strings]=malloc( (strlen(string) + 1) * sizeof(char) );
        strcpy(list[number_of_strings], string);
        number_of_strings++;
        list[number_of_strings]=NULL;
    }
}

void print_list_of_strings(void) {
    int k=0;

    if(list != NULL) {
        for(;k number_of_strings;k++) { // less than
            if(list[k] != NULL) {
                printf("list[%d] = %s\n", k, list[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to make the functions a little more general, so I tried to change the add_string_to_list function so it looked like this:

```
void add_string_to_list(char** test, char *string);
```

in main I changed this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char **local = list;   // is this possible ???

    add_string_to_list(local, "Warrior");
    add_string_to_list(local, "Magician");
    add_string_to_list(local, "Pirate");

    list = local;     // is this possible ???

    print_list_of_strings();

    empty_list_of_strings();

    return 0;
}
```

and finally I changed the add_string_to_list function to this:

```
void add_string_to_list(char **test, char *string) {
    if(test != NULL) {
        test=realloc(test, (number_of_strings + 2) * sizeof(char*));
        test[number_of_strings]=malloc( (strlen(string) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(test[number_of_strings], string);
        number_of_strings++;
        test[number_of_strings]=NULL;
    } else {
        test = malloc( (number_of_strings +2) *sizeof(char *));
        test[number_of_strings]=malloc( (strlen(string) + 1) * sizeof(char) );
        strcpy(test[number_of_strings], string);
        number_of_strings++;
        test[number_of_strings]=NULL;
    }
}
```

And now I do not get any output at all. It is like the add_to_string function does not get the right pointer? Am I sending the pointer to the function in the correct way? Is it possible to do it like this?

Comment: Why are you leaving every-other entry in the array empty?  Also, `add_string_to_list` only needs the `realloc` case, since `realloc` with a `NULL` pointer is equivalent to `malloc`.  Also, also, you have fallen into the `realloc` trap of assigning the return value over your only copy of the pointer.  If it fails and returns `NULL`,  the original memory will remain allocated, but you will no longer know where it is.

Comment: Hello pat, thanks for your comment. I know that this code has lacks when it comes to checking return values from realloc and malloc. I just got stumped over the fact that I could not send my **char pointer to my function to change the values in the function. I need a list of strings that ends with a NULL. It is for a system function on the amiga computer.

Comment: Ahh yes, you're just setting the last entry to `NULL`, but not incrementing `number_of_strings` again.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that, you do not anymore change the actual thing you have, the `local` in `main`, anymore. You just receive a copy of it, and make changes over it.

To do what you are desiring to have, you'll have to pass the address of that `local` to the `add_string_to_list`, and receive a `char ***test` instead of `char **test`; and then also add `*`s behind the `test` occurrences in the function, enclose it with brackets `()` whenever necessary.

Along with the 3 appropriate function calls `add_string_to_list( &local, ... );` in `main`, changing your function definition into the following does the job:

```
void add_string_to_list( char ***test, char *string ) {
    if ( *test != NULL ) {
        *test = realloc( *test, ( number_of_strings + 2 ) * sizeof( char* ) );
        (*test)[number_of_strings] = malloc( ( strlen( string ) + 1 ) * sizeof(char) );
        strcpy( (*test)[number_of_strings], string );
        number_of_strings++;
        (*test)[number_of_strings] = NULL;
    }
    else {
        *test = malloc( ( number_of_strings + 2 ) *sizeof( char * ) );
        (*test)[number_of_strings] = malloc( ( strlen( string ) + 1 ) * sizeof(char) );
        strcpy( (*test)[number_of_strings], string );
        number_of_strings++;
        (*test)[number_of_strings] = NULL;
    }
}
```

One thing: You were also missing some `<` signs in the code you've provided inside `for` loop condition statement parts. As far as I remember, there were 2, maybe 3.

About your comments `// is this possible ???`, yes, they are.

Comment: Hello ThoAppelsin! Thanks for your clarification of this problem. I have struggled with this for a couple of days now, and could not get it to work as I wanted. With your solution it works perfectly.

Comment: @user3439105 I am glad that I've been helpful my friend. You've greeted me with my name as if you knew me from somewhere else; is that right, or is it just me?

Comment: Hello again! No I do not know you from somewhere else, it's just my way of saying hello.   :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `add_string_to_list` function is only modifying its local copy of `test`. If you want to represent your list as a `char **`, then your `add_string_to_list` function would have to be written like this:

```
void add_string_to_list(char ***test, char *string) {
   if (*test != NULL) {
      *test=realloc( ... );
      ...
   } else {
      *test=malloc( ... );
      ...
   }
}
```

Many programmers prefer to avoid this sort of pointer confusion by declaring a struct to represent the list:

```
typedef struct {
   char **strings;
   int numStrings;
} StringList;
```

Then you could initialize the list with:

```
StringList list = { .strings=NULL, .numStrings=0 };
```

And your `add_string_to_list` function would then look like:

```
void add_string_to_list(StringList *list, char *string) {
   if (list->strings != NULL) {
      list->strings = realloc( ... );
      ...
      list->numStrings++;
   } else {
      list->strings = malloc( ... );
      ...
      list->numStrings++;
   }
}
```

However, I hate to repeat myself when writing code, and I also think doing `realloc()` for every new list item is ridiculously inefficient, so I would do:

```
typedef struct {
   char **strings;
   int  numStrings;
   int  capacity;
} StringList;

void init_string_list(StringList *list, int capacity) {
   list->strings = (char **) malloc(capacity * sizeof(char *));
   list->capacity = capacity;
   list->numStrings = 0;
}

void resize_string_list(StringList *list, int increment) {
   list->capacity += increment;
   list->strings = (char **) realloc(list->strings, 
                                     (list->capacity * sizeof(char *)));
}

void add_string_to_list(StringList *list, char *string) {
   if ((list->capacity - list->numStrings) < 1)
      resize_string_list(list, SOME_REASONABLE_INCREMENT_SIZE);

   list->strings[list->numStrings++] = strdup(string);
}

...


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   StringList list = {0};

   init_string_list(&list, SOME_REASONABLE_STARTING_CAPACITY);

   add_string_to_list(&list, "foo");
   add_string_to_list(&list, "bar");
   add_string_to_list(&list, "baz");

   ...
}
```

Of course, this is just for example purposes. There are still numerous ways this code could be improved. But I think you'll agree that `StringList *list` (or something similar) is much nicer looking and thus easier to follow (and maintain) than `char ***list`.

Comment: Hello Mike! I'm very thankful for your input and I'm sure I will use it for my future projects, but in this case I'm not sure I can use any other type than char**, because I'm going to insert this char** list to a system function on the amiga computer that expects to have a char **. BR JJ

Comment: No worries. Use whatever solution you're comfortable with. I should point out, though, that with my solution, you're still representing your list as a `char **`. It's just wrapped in a struct for convenience purposes. You could easily just pass `list->strings` to your system function that requires a `char **`, as in `some_system_function(list->strings)`.